# How to check if one of the superclasses contains a classVariable with a certain name?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I want to write a method that checks the list of all the superclasses ( allSuperclass method) and returns 'true' if one of them has a classVariable with a specific name. If none of them have it it'll return false.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`classVarNames` is a method that returns a collection of the class variable names.

For example, if you'll add this method to *Behavior* class you should get a functionality you're asking for:

```
 superclassesHaveNoClassVar: name
    ^ self allSuperclasses noneSatisfy: [:class |
        class classVarNames includes: name]
```

Nothing special. Just take `allSuperclasses` and check if none of them `includes` a desired variable `name` among it's `classVarNames`.

Answer (score 0):

Just send:

```
superclass allClassVarNames includes: #AClassVariableName
```

to the class in question.
If you want a separate method for this you could place it, as Uko suggested, next to `allClassVarNames` in the protocol of `Behavior`:

```
superclassesIncludeClassVariable: aSymbol
   ^ self superclass allClassVarNames includes: aSymbol
```

Answer (score 0):

In Squeak, there is following method in Behavior whichClassDefinesClassVar:
You can use it like that:

```
^(MyClass whichClassDefinesClassVar: #ThisVariableName) notNil
```